# Snowflake passing parameters to multipule stored procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created individual procs that when ran manually run with 2 date params. BUT I'm trying to write a wrapper proc that calls these procs sequentially. What I have done so far sample code below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SANDBOX.MERC.SP_LOAD_INCR_MERGE_DT("STARTDATE" DATE, "ENDDATE" DATE)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000000)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `call SANDBOX.MERC.SP_LOAD_HDR_INCR_MERGE_DT(?, ?)`,binds: [STARTDATE, ENDDATE]});
var result = stmt.execute();


var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `call SANDBOX.MERC.SP_LOAD_LINEDETAIL_INCR_MERGE_DT(?, ?)`,binds: [STARTDATE, ENDDATE]});
var result = stmt.execute();


var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `call SANDBOX.MERC.header_daily(?, ?)`,binds: [STARTDATE, ENDDATE]});
var result = stmt.execute();

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `call SANDBOX.MERC.lineitem_daily(?, ?)`,binds: [STARTDATE, ENDDATE]});
var result = stmt.execute();

return sql_command;';
```

Any advice would be greatful. I did already look at these urls
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009E2qFHSAZ/how-do-i-bind-a-date-within-a-stored-procedure

Individual calls to these procs via

```
call SANDBOX.MERC.SP_LOAD_HDR_INCR_MERGE_DT ('2021-01-12','2021-01-14' )
```

WORKS as expected. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi Greg great question . I should have posted that:::::-
Execution error in store procedure SP_LOADINCR_MERGE_DT: Invalid binds argumentTue Jan 12 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time). Error: Unsupported type for binding argument 2undefined At Snowflake.createStatement, line 3 position 21 .

Comment: That looks as if it's trying to bind the JavaScript date format. The easiest way to fix that is probably to convert the dates to SfDate types: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#object-sfdate. I'll work on an example if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: To Greg's point, the issue you are having is the conversion of dates/strings.  I have a working example I'll post as an answer now.

Answer (score 5):

The issue you are having is the conversion of dates to strings, and to do so in a fashion Snowflake likes, you can use the .toISOString() function on your variables.

fully working example below.

```
create table stacko_69408091 (
    dt1     DATE,
    dt2     DATE);


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_insert(p1 date, p2 date)
RETURNS ARRAY
LANGUAGE javascript
EXECUTE AS caller
AS 
$$
try {
    var whereAmI = 1;
    var return_array = [];
    var counter = 0;

    var p1_str = "p1: " + P1.toString();
    var p2_str = "p2: " + P2.toString();
    return_array.push(p1_str)
    return_array.push(p2_str)

    var whereAmI = 2;
    var sqlquery = `
        INSERT INTO stacko_69408091 VALUES (?, ?)
    `;

    snowflake.execute({"sqlText" : sqlquery, "binds" : [P1.toISOString(), P2.toISOString()]});

    var whereAmI = 3;
    var query_id_list = snowflake.execute({sqlText: `SELECT LAST_QUERY_ID()::varchar;`});
    if (query_id_list.next()){
      var query_id = query_id_list.getColumnValue(1);
      return_array.push(query_id);
    }
  
    var whereAmI = 4;
    return_array.push("end process");

    return return_array;
    }

catch (err) {
   return_array.push("error found");
   return_array.push("whereAmI: " + whereAmI);
   return_array.push("err.code: " + err.code);
   return_array.push("err.state: " + err.state);
   return_array.push("err.message: " + err.message);
   return_array.push("err.stacktracetxt: " + err.stacktracetxt);
   return return_array;
}

$$;

CALL sp_insert('2021-09-01'::date, '2021-10-01'::date);
select * from stacko_69408091;




CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_main(STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000000)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `call sp_insert(?, ?)`,binds: [STARTDATE.toISOString(), ENDDATE.toISOString()]});
var result = stmt.execute();


var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `call sp_insert(?, ?)`,binds: [STARTDATE.toISOString(), ENDDATE.toISOString()]});
var result = stmt.execute();


return "done";

$$
;


CALL sp_main('2021-09-01'::date, '2021-10-01'::date);
select * from stacko_69408091;
```

Comment: accepted answer Rich.  For anyone that wants the one liner answer. 
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `call SANDBOX.MERC.SP_LOAD_HDR_INCR_MERGE_DT(?, ?)`,binds: [STARTDATE.toISOString(), ENDDATE.toISOString()]});
var result = stmt.execute();
... and this takes the date from wrapper proc and pushes to individual procs. THANK YOU VERY MUCH.